# XPath Java Selenium trying click a value in one col based on the text in another

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I need to click a button in column 5 of an html table based on text found in column 1.  Column 1 is username column 5 is a button with no `ID` I need to click.  Each table cell has multiple `Li` in it.  so the first cell has Name, Email, Company each in a `Li`.

I want to say if `user name = foo` then click button in col 5

my current xpath to find the user name in column 1 is as such (and works)

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr//td//li[contains(text(), 'Edith Fields')]"));
```

but I don't know how to then say now that I have the row use that to click button in that row column 5.  Also I assume that xpath I have return a web element for the specific `<Li>` not the `<TR>` so I might need to so get its parent?

Not pasting the entire table HTML as its large but this is one row col 1 and col 5

```
<tr class=" ev_dhx_skyblue">
<td valign="middle" bgcolor="white" align="left" title=" Edith Fields email@foo.com ">
<ul>
<li title=" Edith Fields email@foo.com "> Edith Fields </li>
<li class="last" title=" Edith Fields email@foo.com "> email@foo.com </li>
</ul>


<td valign="middle" bgcolor="white" align="left">
<ul>
<li>
<li class="last">
<a onclick="liftAjax.lift_ajaxHandler("ffffgggg=true", null, null, null); return false;">Reset Password</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try using below xpath :-

```
String xpath = "(.//td[descendant::li[contains(text(), 'Edith Fields')]]/following::td//a[contains(text(), 'Reset Password')])[1]"
```

Or

```
String xpath = "(.//td[descendant::li[contains(text(), 'Edith Fields')]]/following::a[contains(text(), 'Reset Password')])[1]"
```

Or

```
String xpath = "(.//td[descendant::li[contains(text(), 'Edith Fields')]]/following::a)[1]"
```

Use anyone of these above `xpath` to find element as below :-

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that it will always remain 5th column, use this

```
//td[contains(.,'Edith Fields')]/following-sibling::td[4]//a
```

else use this

```
//td[contains(.,'Edith Fields')]/following-sibling::td[contains(.,'Reset Password')]//a
```